# Setting value in select drop down not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular and we are rewriting our app in it.  I can't seem to figure out something very basic.  I am trying to replace the option value to the Id after the data gets fetched.  I created a jsbin to just do it for static data, but I can't seem to get the Id set to the value in the option.

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("testApp", []);

angular.module("testApp").controller("testController", function ($scope) {
  $scope.name="hi";
  
  $scope.projects = [{Id:"12345", Name:"crystal"}, {Id:"9987", Name:"emerald"}];
  
});
```

http://jsbin.com/dazolelu/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the .id from proj

```
<select ng-model="selectedProject" ng-options="proj as proj.Name for proj in projects"></select>

  {{selectedProject.Id}}
```

here is the url : http://jsbin.com/rocajeja/1/

this is the edit url : http://jsbin.com/rocajeja/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your controller

```
 $scope.selectedProject= $scope.projects[0].Id;
```

This will tell the controller to set the default value i.e $scope.selectedProject to the first project.

[JsBin fiddle](http://jsbin.com/mojatufa/3/edit)